# Authentication in PowerBI Workspace with App registration using TOM in C#

Tags: c#, powerbi, ssas-tabular

I'm writing an Azure function to gather some metadata on my Datasets in my Premium workspace.

Now I've found loads of different how-to's but all of them skip over the part of authenticating their session.

Please find my sample code below, it wil just print a Pipe separated list of the datasets.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular;


namespace IrisTabularManagement
{
    public class TabularModel
    {
        private string workspaceConnection;
        private Server server;
        public TabularModel(string Workspace)
        {
            workspaceConnection = Workspace;
            server = new Server();
            connect();
        }

        private void connect()
        {
            string connectString = $"DataSource={workspaceConnection};User ID=xxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxx;";
            // connect to the Power BI workspace referenced in connect string
            server.Connect(connectString);
        }

        public string getDatasets()
        {
            // enumerate through datasets in workspace to display thier names
            string result = "";
            foreach (Database database in server.Databases)
            {
                result += database.Name + "|";
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone guid me to how I should authenticate using my App registration (Client & Secret)?

Kind regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found it.

2 things:

1: The connection string should look like this

```
string connString = $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data source=powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/<tenant>/<workspacename>;Initial catalog=<datasetname>;User ID=app:{appId};Password={authKey};";
```

2: The default URL you get from PoewerBI is not complete enough. You also use you tenant ID. So replace "myorg" in the URL with your tenantID.

This is my final code

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular;


namespace IrisTabularManagement
{
    public class TabularModel
    {
        private string workspaceConnection;
        private Server server;
        private string appId;
        private string authKey;
        public TabularModel(string Workspace, string app, string key)
        {
            workspaceConnection = Workspace;
            appId = app;
            authKey = key;
            server = new Server();

            connect();
        }

        private void connect()
        {
            string connectString = $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data source={workspaceConnection};User ID=app:{appId};Password={authKey};";
            // connect to the Power BI workspace referenced in connect string
            server.Connect(connectString);
        }

        public string getDatasets()
        {
            // enumerate through datasets in workspace to display thier names
            string result = "";
            foreach (Database database in server.Databases)
            {
                result += database.Name + "|";
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```